# Target and update a specific element in a table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an assignment to build a simple static CRUD page using nothing but HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I'm almost done but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make the update function work.

The idea is to click on the pencil icon and then rewrite whatever is in that field. However, I'm unable to figure out how to expand that functionality to all three fields, it just works on one.

Heres the [page](https://renanmdp.github.io/nova-singular/sistema.html). If you click on "cadastrar-se" it will create three "td" with the pencil, but only one works(the one saying "locado?"). Snippets are below but I used localStorage so it won't run properly.

The function of interest is at the bottom of the page, called "updateItems()".

I thank you in advance for any help.

```js
const createTd = item => {
  const Td = document.createElement("td");
  Td.innerHTML = item;
  return Td;
};

const createTdWithI = item => {
  const Td = document.createElement("td");
  const i = document.createElement("i");
  Td.innerHTML = item;
  Td.setAttribute("class", "tdEdit");
  Td.appendChild(i).setAttribute("class", "fas fa-edit");
  return Td;
}

const appendChildren = (parent, children) => {
  children.forEach(child => {
    parent.setAttribute("class", "tr");
    parent.appendChild(child);
  });
};

document.querySelector("#addClientBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const clientName = document.querySelector("#name").value;
  const clientMovie = document.querySelector("#movie").value;
  const clientLocado = document.querySelector("#rentStatus").value;

  localStorage.setItem("clientName", clientName);
  localStorage.setItem("clientMovie", clientMovie);
  localStorage.setItem("clientLocado", clientLocado);

  const getTbody = document.querySelector("#tbody");
  const createTr = document.createElement("tr");
  const appendTr = getTbody.appendChild(createTr);

  const items = [
    createTdWithI(localStorage.getItem("clientName")),
    createTdWithI(localStorage.getItem("clientMovie")),
    createTdWithI(localStorage.getItem("clientLocado")),
    createTd('<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>')
  ];

  appendChildren(appendTr, items);
  
  deleteRow();
  updateItems();
});


// Deleta as linhas na tabela
function deleteRow() {
  let trashIcon = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-trash");
  trashIcon[trashIcon.length - 1].addEventListener("click", event => {
    trashIcon = event.target;
    trashIcon.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(trashIcon.parentNode.parentNode);
  });
}

function updateItems() {
  let editIcon = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-edit");
  // let targetText = document.querySelectorAll(".tdEdit");
  editIcon[editIcon.length - 1].addEventListener("click", event => {
    editIcon = event.target;
    editIcon.innerText = "test";

    // for (let i = 0; i < editIcon.length; i++) {
    //   editIcon.length = i;
    //   editIcon[i] = event.target;
    //   editIcon[i].innerText = "testLocado";
    // }


    // if (editIcon.length === editIcon.length - 1) {
    //   editIcon = event.target;
    //   editIcon.innerText = "testLocado";
    // } else if (editIcon.length === editIcon.length - 2) {
    //   editIcon = event.target;
    //   editIcon.parentNode.innerText = "testFilme";
    // } else if (editIcon.length === editIcon.length - 3) {
    //   editIcon = event.target;
    //   editIcon.parentNode.innetText = "testNome";
    // }
      
  });
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Renan Martineli de Paula" />
    <meta name="description" content="locadora de filmes Nova Singular processo seletivo desenvolvimento - sistema" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vp86vTRFVJgpjF9jiIGPEEqYqlDwgyBgEF109VFjmqGmIY/Y4HV4d3Gp2irVfcrp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" /> -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="sistema.js" defer></script>
    <title>Sistema</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Bem vindo(a), <span id="userNameWelcome"></span>.

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Cadastrar cliente</legend>

      <label for="name">
        <p>Nome</p>
        <input type="text" id="name" required />
      </label>

      <label for="movie">
        <p>Filme</p>
        <input type="text" id="movie" required />
      </label>

      <br />

      <label for="rentStatus">
        <span>Locado?</span>
        <select name="locado" id="rentStatus" required>
          <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
          <option value="Não">Não</option>
        </select>
      </label>

      <br />

      <button id="addClientBtn">Cadastrar</button>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="text" id="searchMenu" placeholder="Procure por clientes"/>

    <table id="clientTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Filme</th>
          <th>Locado?</th>
          <!-- <th>Modificar</th> -->
          <th>Deletar</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tbody">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
  
  <script>
    // Mostra o nome do usuário na tela de boas vindas
    document.querySelector("#userNameWelcome").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("userName");
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function updateItems() {
let editIcon = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-edit");
// let targetText = document.querySelectorAll(".tdEdit");
for(let icon of editIcon){
icon.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
editIcon = event.target;
editIcon.innerText = "test";
}, false);
}
```